Plane or helicopter crash into mountain
I remember watching a movie years ago (late 90's) which started with either a plane or helicopter crashed into the side of a mountain. If I recall correctly, there were kids on board (they survived) and the mountain was snow covered. 
It wasn't an action movie (i.e. didn't get shot down) - it was a survival drama.
It's not Alive.

I'm not sure there's going to be enough information here to answer it.  Anything else you can give us?

There's a LOT of movies w helicoper crashes...

It wasn't an action movie (i.e. didn't get shot down) - it was a survival drama.
I know there isn't a lot of information. I've been searching for this movie for a while now and thought I would try anyways.

@colti edit your original question rather than adding in the comments

Ok, I'm going to have a go, could it be Alaska?

Released in 1996
Set in Alaska (shockingly)
A plane crashes in the mountains


Looks like it...

I think this is it actually! Thanks.

@colti - great!
